# How to communicate an UIView from a XIB child to an UIView from a parent XIB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, interface-builder

I'd like to know if is possible to tap somewhere (or do something else) inside an UIView loaded from XIB file and trigger an action of an UIView from a parent XIB (like change the title of an UIButton in the parent UIView). This is a fragment of the code NewsController class interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewsPage.h"
@interface NewsController : UIViewController {
    // Some objects
    UIButton *loadButton;
    UIView *newsView;
    NewsPage *newsPage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *loadButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *newsView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NewsPage *newsPage;
@end
```

and this is a fragment of the class implementation of NewsPage, where I load the child XIB:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Some code
    newsPage = [[NewsPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsPage" bundle:nil];
    [newsView addSubview:newsPage.view];
    // Some other code
}
```

This is a fragment of code inside NewsPage class interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewsController.h"
@interface NewsPage : UIViewController {
    NewsController *newsController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NewsController *newsController;
@end
```

and this is a fragment of the class implementation

```
- (void)tapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // Some code
    NewsController *newsController = [[NewsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"News" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"Current button title is: %@\n", newsController.loadButton.titleLabel.text);        
    newsController.loadButton.titleLabel.text = @"New text goes here!";
    NSLog(@"Current button title is: %@\n", newsController.loadButton.titleLabel.text);
    // Some other code
}
```

With this code (and after some wiring in IB) I see the correct title in debugger but the simulator doesn't update the title change. My guess is that the child UIViews are parallel to the parent's UIViews and even if I do something like this:

```
[newsController.loadButton removeFromSuperview]
```

there is no change in the parents UIView hierarchy because the child UIViews "aren't inside" of parent UIView. I hope somebody can help with this because is very frustating. In advance, thank you very much.

Comment: Does the xib connect to owner object correctly ? It sounds like the titleLabel don't exist in view's hierarchy. So it won't be displayed.

Comment: @Toro: Yes, the owner object is correctly connected but I don't know if a XIB objects loaded in a parent UIView belongs to the hierarchy of the parent and if does, why don't update any changes made from child UIView to parent UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue that I see is that you are accessing some of the elements in the NewsController that might not yet have been unpacked from the NIB since they are done lazily when the view is needed. Try to access the .view member of the controller, which should force the load, before you reference those items. This is a gotcha that everyone seems to hit until the lazy load idea is grokked.

```
NewsController *newsController = [[NewsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"News" bundle:nil];
newController.view; //hopefully this doens't get optimized out. If so, change it a bit.
NSLog(@"Current button title is: %@\n", newsController.loadButton.titleLabel.text);
```

Comment: Thank you @DavidNeiss for your answer. I try as you said but there is no change. I even try with looping with `for (UIView *view in [newsController.view subviews]) {
  if (view.tag == 99) {
   
   NSLog(@"Enter tag #99 with hidden property %d\n", newsController.loadButton.hidden);
   [view removeFromSuperview];
  }
  NSLog(@"UIView in newsController #%d\n", view.tag);
 }` In seems that the code works but it doesn't update in the simulator yet.

Comment: Are you transitioning over to the newsController modal view with - (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
?

Comment: No, because newsController is not a modal view but the "main view". NewsPage XIB is loaded inside an UIView of NewsController and inside of it is where I tap and trigger tapAction:gestureRecognizer.

Comment: Ok, sorry, Im trying to figure this out. So NewController is first view controller, then NewPage is presented modally from there upon some kind of action? button press? So when something happens in NewPage, you want to affect a view in NewsController? If so, you can move up the view controller chain from your current VC via the "*parentViewController" ivar.

Comment: NewsPage is not presented modally but inside an UIView of NewsController XIB and the button to press is inside that UIView, but yes, like you said, "when something happens in NewPage, you want to affect a view in NewsController". I update the OP with more information about the NewsPage class.

Comment: Ok, I'm still having problems with the issue of bringing in another view by alloc'ing a view controller object from a XIB and not transitioning it it, but lets say that works. Inside the tapAction:gestureRecognizer you are re-alloc'ing a NewsController object, but yet the original one exists. Why not point to the original object?

Comment: Well I tried this thing about bringing in another VC from within one VC and it does appear to work, although I haven't seen that pattern before. However, I still think that you are alloc'ing a new NewsController and you probably want to point to the original one since that is what is being rendered to the screen, not this new one.

Comment: As you suggest, I delete all UIView reallocating with initWithNibName and instead add and wire the corresponding VC with IB in the hope to point to the original and now it seems to work! (don't know if better, but at least it work and with one line less of code per VC). I do it using "nested superviews", like in this example that removes the root UIViews in my particular hierarchy: `for (UIView *view in [self.view.superview.superview.superview.superview subviews]) { [view removeFromSuperview]; } }`. Thank you very much!.

Comment: Well, Im not sure I'm following, but what the heck, if it's working good. If you could upvote this answer, I think at least I can get some reputation for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, when the parent wants to know something the Child will tell it, you set a delegate on the child as the parent, then in the child code you check to see if that delegate exists first of all, and then make sure it responds to the selector you will send. then you send it a message.

a good way to implement this in through the use of @protocol's

Here is a link with some basic information about it

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html